# Assign Dictionary<int, List<string>> to empty new declared dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

I have one dictionary like as below:

```
var objListColor = new List<String>() { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow" };
var objListDirection = new List<String>() { "East", "West", "North", "South" };

var dictFrom = new Dictionary<int, List<String>>();
dictFrom.Add(1, objListColor);
dictFrom.Add(2, objListDirection);
```

and I have the another dictionary declaration like as below:

```
var dictTo = new Dictionary<int, List<String>>();
```

I want to populate `dictTo` with `dictFrom`'s keys and values. How can I populate with LINQ or C#? i want to assign value and key with foreach or for loop.

Comment: It is called a Copy Constructor and Dictionary has one. It is worth mentioning that it performs a shallow copy. Execute this: `var dictTo = new Dictionary<int, List<String>>(dictFrom); dictFrom[1][0] = null;` and then see the value of `dictTo` - which the first string in the first item will be `null`

Comment: For example, you have two dictionaries.dictFrom has value and key. 
var dictto = new Dictionary<int, List<onemodelclass>>(); var dicfrom = new Dictionary<int, List<differentonemodelclass>>();   How can you populate dicTo with dicFrom with using your copy constructor.

Comment: you can't.. But the way to do so is a completely different question...

Comment: @Dvlpr if you have a way to map `onemodelclass` to `differentmodelclass` then you can project it like `var dictTo = dictFrom.Select(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.ConvertToDifferentModelClass())`

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries have a copy constructor for this:

```
var dictTo = new Dictionary<int, List<String>>(dictFrom);
```

This copies the contents of dictFrom into dictTo. Modifying dictTo will not impact dictFrom (and vice versa), since dictTo is an actual shallow copy.

Lists and some other collections have similar functionality.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: var dictto = new Dictionary<int, List<onemodelclass>>(); var dicfrom = new Dictionary<int, List<differentonemodelclass>>(); how can you use var dictTo = new Dictionary<int, List<String>>(dictFrom);

Comment: @Dvlpr: It won't work if the key is a list of a different type. You should probably just write a loop in that case.

Comment: how can i write loop ? When i write loop, the error is occurred like as above.

Comment: But the problem in the loop above, which you added to the question, is not the one you're describing now (where the generic lists are different types). Which problem do you need to solve? You should probably make a separate question for what you actually need to solve. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Dictionary's constructor that receives another Dictionary:

```
var dictTo = new Dictionary<int, List<String>>(dictFrom);
```

Refer to MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz(v=vs.110).aspx